# Object reference error running checkbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I get an Object reference error when I run the code below. I want on check of the checkbox to update a database table.

```
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.ShippingDetail.Shiped, new { @id = item.ShippingDetail.ShippingDetailsID, @class = "chks"});
        </tr>
    }
}


  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {

    $(document).on("click", "input.chks", function (e) {
        var _this = $(this);
        var isChecked = _this.is(':checked');
        $.post("@Url.Action("Update","Home")?id=" + _this.attr("id") +
                                      "&newValue=" + isChecked, function (data) {
                                          // do something with the response
                                      });

   });
});
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update(int id, bool newValue)
    {
        //do your saving here.
        return Json(true);
    }
```

In Model I have included a column shiped, which is set to bit in table type. At the moment all entries are set to false. Also on checking box, javascript does not seem to be reached.

```
 public partial class ShippingDetail
{
    public ShippingDetail()
    {
        this.UserProfiles = new HashSet<UserProfile>();
    }

    public int ShippingDetailsID { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public Boolean Shiped { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: Apparently your `item` or `item.ShippingDetail` is `null`

Comment: ok I got ride of the error, but on checking the checkbox nothing happens i.e. the database is not altered, what can I do here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$(document).on("click", "input.chks", function (e) {
    var _this = $(this);
    var isChecked = _this.is('input:checkbox:checked');
    $.post('@Url.Action("Update","Home")',
           {
               id=this.attr("id") ,
               newValue= isChecked
           }, function (data) {
               // do something with the response
           });

});
</script>
```

Comment: ok I got ride of the error, but on checking the checkbox nothing happens i.e. the database is not altered, what can I do here

Comment: Are you getting updated check box value while debugging the application. If updated value is correct its means some error in Action